# Appending list items into a list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a `list` which has the following structure:

```
data = [[], [], ..., []]  # N sub-lists
```

I am receiving data from a process over which I have no control in the following format:

```
new_entries = ['foo', 'bar', ..., 'foobar']  # guaranteed N entries
```

**What is the best way to have the i<sub>th</sub> item of the `new_entries` stored in the i<sub>th</sub> sublist of `data`?**

So that the result after one arrival would be:

```
data = [['foo'], ['bar'], ..., ['foobar']]
```

*Is the following as good as it gets?*

```
for i, item in enumerate(new_entries):
    data[i].append(item)
```

Comment: use `zip` instead of using indices

Answer (score 3):

Using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#zip) seems a little more elegant than `enumerate`, but generally there is nothing wrong with your code. For any production-level code that anybody will ever have to read or maintain, this (or yours) should be the way to go:

```
for lst, entry in zip(data, new_entries):
    lst.append(entry)
```

If you feel the pathologic urge to do it in one line, you could use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#map) or a comprehension:

```
list(map(lambda x: x[0].append(x[1]), zip(data, new_entries)))  # Py3
map(lambda (x, y): x.append(y), zip(data, new_entries))  # Py2

# or shorter, thx to Stefan Pochmann:
# Py3: any as a more space-efficient consumer than list
any(map(list.append, data, new_entries))  
map(list.append, data, new_entries)  # Py2

[lst.append(entry) for lst, entry in zip(data, new_entries)]
```

but I would strongly recommend not sacrificing readability for saving lines. In both cases the mutation of the lists in `data` is more of a side effect!

And, of course, a good old list comprehension (that actually uses the result of the comprehension) can be used but does come with performance issues as the concatenation is `O(M+N)`:

```
data = [lst + [entry] for lst, entry in zip(data, new_entries)]
```

Comment: @PaulPanzer I edited the answer with two versions that work for me in 2.7 and 3.5

Comment: Btw: `map(list.append, data, new_entries)`.

Comment: same as the comment in the other answer, comprehensions or map are not meant to be used with mutable operations, `append` is.

Comment: @DanielSanchez I was just about to add the warning for that.

Comment: Please please please **do not** use `.append` with `map` or with list-comprehensions.

Comment: Just use a for-statement if you are going to have side effects.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I totally agree, hence the qualification of those approaches. But the question indicates some academic brevity ambition, so I thought I'd mention those.

Comment: Space-efficient Python 3 version: `any(map(list.append, data, new_entries))`

Comment: @StefanPochmann LOL, true,  that makes it even more a side effect.

Comment: @StefanPochmann ugh. might as well use `collections.deque(map(list.append, data, new_entries), maxlen=0)` i.e. the `consume` recipe from `itertools` docs...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Why? That's far longer, ugly, and probably less efficient.

Answer (score 1):

If the length of `data` is the same as `new_entries`, then you can merely encapsulating each item in a list:

```
new_entries = ['foo', 'bar', ..., 'foobar']
final_entries = [[i] for i in new_entries]
```

To add new data at any time, you can use a class:

```
class Stream:
   def __init__(self):
       pass
   def __setitem__(self, name, stream):
        self.__dict__[name] = map(lambda x:[x], stream) if name not in self.__dict__ else [d+[b] for d, b in zip(self.__dict__[name], stream)]
   def __getitem__(self, name):
        return self.__dict__[name]
   def __repr__(self):
        return "{}({})".format(self.__class__.__name__, ', '.join("{}:{}".format(a, str(list(b))) for a, b in self.__dict__.items()))

stream = Stream()
stream['first'] = ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar']
print(stream.first)
>>>[['foo'], ['bar'], ['foobar']]
stream['first'] = ['foobar', 'newfoo', 'anotherfoo']
print(stream.first)
>>>[['foo', 'foobar'], ['bar', 'newfoo'], ['foobar', 'anotherfoo']]
```

Comment: and what do I do when the next `new_entries` comes along?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis that seems like a different problem, since part of `final_entries` will already be filled, you would have to start adding the new entries right after the last filled list in `final_entries`. I will add an answer to account for that. One minute...

Comment: That is the only problem. If my question needs clarification I will update.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis please see my recent edit. I added a class-based solution to allow you to effectively update your stream while specifying attributes for simple namespace-like implementation.

Comment: Appreciate the effort. But after the second `stream['first']` assignment, the result should be `[['foo', 'foobar'], ['bar', 'newfoo'], ['foobar', 'anotherfoo']]`. Take a look at my code snippet on the question. The *N* stays constant

Comment: Exactly. I do not think the last class implementation is what the OP is looking for.